# AngularJS - directive with ngModelController - asynchronous $formatters

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-model

I have a directive where I require the ng-model directive and use the ngModelController to parse and format the model value.

My problem is that in some cases, in order to format the model value I need to get some extra data from the server. That causes me a problem to return the view value in time for angular to use it.

See this example:

```
ngModelController.$formatters.push(function (modelValue) {
    var obj = { CustomerID: modelValue.id };

    if (dataService.mainProperty() === scope.text) {
        obj[scope.text] = modelValue.value;
    }
    else {
        /* In this case I need to get from server 
           the value of the property to show in the view */

        dataService.getItem(obj.id, scope.text).then(function (item) {
            scope.formattedValue[scope.text] = item[scope.text];
        });
    }

    return obj;
});
```

Comment: You wont be able to use formatters for that, they are synchronous per design. overrides the model controller $render instead

Comment: Can you guide me how (with an example even better...)?

Comment: What exactly the async data you need to fetch your server to get is used for ?

Comment: It used to display the correct value in a select control. you can see a full example here ([link](http://dojo.telerik.com/UhUMu/3) I'm using kendo controls)